# How to use spec2 to assert the difference of two integers are less than 1000?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

Specs2 test:

```
val num1: Int = getNum1();
val num2: Int = getNum2();

math.abs(num2 - num1) must beLessThan(1000)
```

This may work, but is not elegant. Is there some better solution to do it?

---

Update:

I mean I want to find or create some matcher that I can write with:

```
num1 must beLessOrMoreThan(num2, 1000)
```

Comment: Why not elegant? For me that's fine. There is not specific matcher to check numeric difference as far as I know.

Comment: You can always create custom matchers http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write

```
(num2 - num1) must beCloseTo(0 +/- 1000)
```